# Does Svg Animate only start after DOM is loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, dom, svg-animate

I am trying to implement a simple preloader to wait for the page to load, but I noticed the animation doesn't start till the page is loaded

Is Animate starting only after load?

If so, how would I go to animate a simple preloader before the page is loaded?

Comment: You have created code; please show us the code...

Comment: In JavaScript, you would use the DOM content loaded event to fire off an animation - because that's the first event that fires: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event (after HTML parsing, but before images etc.)

There is a way to customize starting events on SMIL using the begin attribute value list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin - but it's not clear what the "load" event refers to.